# Listing the instruction sets used by a compiled object - for ARM and X86

Tags: linux, disassembly

This question is for ARM and X86 architectures and for both executables and objects, i would like to have a list of the instructions sets used by a compiled piece of code: is this possible?

Comment: Which OS are you using / building for?

Comment: @OrangeDog Ubuntu 64 bit 12.04 is my actual OS of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet is only my quick and dirty solution to your problem (only for Intel mnemonics).

```
objdump --no-show-raw-insn -M intel -d /usr/bin/objdump | awk '{if ($2 !~ ":" && $2 != "data32" && $2 != "file" && $2 != "of" && length($2) > 0) {print $2}}' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Linux system, and are thus dealing with [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files, the `file` command should report what the instruction set is.

#### Edit

It appears what you actually want is an assembly listing (I suggest you edit the question to make this clear), which can be obtained using `objdump -d obj.o`. Other options are available, check `man objdump` for details.

Alternatively, if you are building the object code yourself, you can instruct your compiler to output the assmebler (e.g. `gcc -S src.c`).

Comment: `file` is giving me the architecture, not the complete list of instruction sets, i want a list filled with this kind of labels http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings